# Gantt Highcharts layout cutoff

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, highcharts

I have created a gantt chart after processing an incoming data. Data is coming right but last row is not displaying properly (getting cutoff). I have checked it for long time but unable to figure out the issue.

```
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/rohitkatarya7/pen/mdwWaWd
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks like a bug in Highhcarts Gantt, you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

As a workaround, you can recalculate y-axis extremes. Example:

```
 chart: {
   events: {
     load: function() {
       var yAxis = this.yAxis[0];
       yAxis.setExtremes(null, yAxis.max + 0.5);
     }
   }
 }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uho1rmf3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek ... Its working for me.